# How can I find out the type of a NSDictionary element?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

How can I find out the type of a NSDictionary element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's various sorts of introspection you can perform on any  object at runtime, contained within the NSObject protocol.

[http://developer.apple.com/documentation/](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html)

e.g.

You can test the class of an object at runtime by comparing it to a class object, which you can obtain by sending a `class` message.

`BOOL test = [self isKindOfClass:[SomeClass class]];`